# Does Learning a Spell From a Scroll Consume the Scroll?

Tags: spells, magic-items, pathfinder-2e

In the [Learn a Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=25) action, it says:

> You can gain access to a new spell of your tradition from someone who knows that spell or from magical writing like a spellbook or scroll.

The [rules for scrolls](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=720) doesn't seem to mention it at all.

So RAW, I don't see anything that says that learning a spell from a scroll consumes the scroll.

However, two decades solid of playing DnD 3, 3.5 and PF1 scream at me that of course it does.

Am I missing something? The only discussion I've found about this thus far is a reddit thread that seems to agree with me, but I wanted more opinions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No

As you've mentioned, there's no rule that the scroll would be consumed in PF2.

Learning a Spell just requires access to a source, and a *scroll* of the spell is noted to qualify as a source. The only expenditure for this activity is described as the materials expended depending on the result of the character's skill check.

Comment: Thank you!

I often think that a 2nd-ed game, or something clearly similar to another game (pathfinder vs. dnd3.5 for example) should have a "here are things that are explicitly different from the thing you played before" section. I mean, PF2 is a big overhaul, but there could definitely be some core points (maybe on a FAQ or something).